# Possible to see POST when no option in BIOS to disable splash screen or quiet boot?

Tags: display, bios, post, splash

Is there keyboard key or combination of keys you can press during POST to make the manufacturer splash screen go away so you can see the POST screen?

The BIOS on my Dell Optiplex systems does not give the option to disable splash screen or disable quiet boot so all I ever see is the splash screen.  But I want to see the POST screen instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was finally able to open a Dell Community forum account (Dell.com is a very glitchy and confusing site) and posted my question there, too.

Got an answer from a 12-year Dell employee who says that unless the BIOS on your Dell system allows to disable "Quiet Boot" or to disable "Splash Screen", there is no way to view a POST screen.